# linq iteration need for single row?

Tags: linq

when i form the following code

```
Rabbit[] rbt=
new Rabbit[]
{
   new Rabbit{ Name="Jobby", Vegetable=new Vegetable{ VegiName="carrot"}},
   new Rabbit{ Name="hobby", Vegetable=new Vegetable{ VegiName="Beetroot"}}
};

var s = from bt in rbt where
        bt.Vegetable.VegiName.CompareTo("carrot") == 0 select bt;

foreach (var v in s)
{
                Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",v.Vegetable.VegiName,v.Name);
}
```

my query returns single row only, then why do i need foreach iteration ? can't i use

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",s.Vegetable.VegiName,s.Name); directly ?
```

Answer (score 8):

How is the compiler meant to know that your query will only return a single row?
Suppose you changed your data to include another carrot - or no carrot at all - what would you expect to happen.

If you should definitely get a single result, call `Single` to get it. If you may get multiple results, call `First`. If you may get multiple results or none, call `FirstOrDefault`. If you may get zero or one result, call `SingleOrDefault`. For example, for the first case:

```
var s = from bt in rbt where
        bt.Vegetable.VegiName.CompareTo("carrot") == 0 select bt;

var veg = s.Single();

Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",veg.Vegetable.VegiName,veg.Name);
```

Or alternatively:

```
var veg = rbt.Where(bt => bt.Vegetable.VegiName.CompareTo("carrot") == 0)
             .Single();
Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}",veg.Vegetable.VegiName,veg.Name);
```

Comment: what is the wrong in

var k = from bt in rbt from c in bt.Vegetable where c.VegiName.CompareTo("carrot") == 0 select c;   declaration ?

Comment: "from bt in rbt from c in bt.Vegetable" won't work because bt.Vegetable is not IEnumerable.  In "from c in ...", the ... has to be IEnumerable.

Comment: I saw   from c in customers,
                o in c.Orders
        where o.OrderDate >= new DateTime(1998, 1, 1)
        select new {c.CustomerID, o.OrderID, o.OrderDate};
from microsoft site so i asked.

Comment: In that sample, c.Orders is enumerable (it is that Customer's collection of Orders).  In your case, the analogy would be if a Rabbit has a collection of Vegetables -- then the query you were asking about would definitely be appropriate (and necessary).

Comment: You mean something similar to List<Orders> or other collection right?

Comment: Yes, exactly that (anything that implements IEnumerable<Order> in fact).

Answer (score 2):

Because the type of the query `IEnumerable<Rabbit>`, not `Rabbit`.  You can get what you want, though, by using a FirstOrDefault() or SingleOrDefault() at the end of your query.

```
var s = (from bt in rbt
         where bt.Vegetable.VegiName.CompareTo("carrot") == 0
         select bt)
        .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Single method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155325.aspx) to return a single value. Use [SingleOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342451.aspx) if you suspect it may be null (ie. no results returned).

```
Rabbit result = s.SingleOrDefault();

if (result != null)
{
    // use result
    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", result.Vegetable.VegiName, result.Name);
}
```

As others have mentioned, the alternative is to use First or FirstOrDefault to take the first result returned, if the query returns numerous results.

Answer (score 1):

No, because LINQ does not know at compile time that s will return only a single row.  Use the First() or Single() operator:

```
var v = (from bt in rbt where
         bt.Vegetable.VegiName.CompareTo("carrot") == 0 
         select bt)
        .First();
```